# Typescript 2.0 Path mapping doesn't work

Tags: typescript2.0

I'm trying to use the new path mapping features from typescript 2.0:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript

But I just can't get it to work no matter how many manipulations I did.
I've searched all over the internet (also in stackoverflow) but non of the answers solved my issue.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "components/*": [
            "client/components/*"
        ],
        "services/*": [
            "client/service/*"
        ]
    }
},
"exclude": [
    "../node_modules",
    "node_modules"
]
```

I have a file that is located in:

- /client/components/bars/topBar.component.ts

And I try to import it like this:

- import { TopBarComponent } from 'components/topBar.component'

And I'm getting this error:

- "Cannot find module 'components/topBar.component'"

Comment: Hi, did you figure out this problem? Cause I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I'm still having trouble solving this one @chaonextdoor

Comment: have you figured it out yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no @ZhenyangHua

Comment: Any update on this issue ?